# How to get a Listbox to read to a Listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, openfiledialog

I am trying to open any selected textfile and have the text input be sent to a listbox... Originally I wrote this code for a textbox which worked great now that I am converting it to a listbox it doesnt seem to work so much. I left the default item names in order for better understanding of what is going on.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
   {
      label1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
      listBox1.Items.Add = File.ReadAllText(label1.Text);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(label1.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadLines(label1.Text).ToArray());
```

Comment: that will not compile

Comment: `.AddRange()` won't compile as you have it written.  It requires either an `object[] items` or `ListBox.ObjectCollection value`.

Comment: Switching to this actually gives me two separate errors that it does not like this method for some reason

Comment: Sorry, Ive modifier my code to fit into `AddRange(object[])`

Answer (score 0):

`.Add()` is a method and you are treating it like a property.

Try this code instead:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(File.ReadAllText(label1.text));
```

Comment: This will not break the string into lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                label1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                //till here the same
                //open filestream
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                //loop trough lines
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //add line to listbox
                    listBox1.Items.Add ( line);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This tells me "the name line does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadLines("SomeFile.txt").ToArray();
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(line);
}
```